# Is there any limit on the weight of a luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, legal, airlines

I am guessing that each airline has different luggage policy but I was wondering if there is a maximum luggage weight per passenger (assuming the passenger can pay the additional weight)?

If there is, can a very heavy (> 50kg) luggage be rejected?

Comment: What's very heavy? Even if you have a large allowance or are willing to pay, there is also typically a limit *per piece* of luggage, for handling/work safety reasons (someone has to lift them at several points during the process).

Comment: Do we know this limit? That's the one I am interested to know.

Comment: 32 kg seems typical.

Comment: Are you asking whether your luggage will be rejected, or if you'll be charged a fee, or if you need to make special arrangements? Anything can be sent on an aircraft, for a price, including automobiles and space stations. In any case, you'll need to specify which airline you're using, and precisely what your concern is. And if possible, indicate the size and weight (if not identity) of what you're trying to transport.

Answer (score 4):

Now you have clarified (in comments on the question) that you are interested in the mass range of baggage that is too heavy for the free allowance, but may still be carried without special arrangements, the policy may well vary from airline to airline - but probably not by much.

In https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/extra-overweight-baggage , BA notes that:

> Charges are applied for bags over 23kg and up to 32kg. Bags over 32kg
>   cannot be checked in and must be shipped separately as freight or
>   cargo

which agrees with Relaxed's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the type of *cargo* an aircraft can carry. After all, the same 777 you use to fly a long haul flight is the one that is used to transport everything from aircraft engines to animals.

*The restrictions that are in place are due to safety and prohibit carrying specific amounts or types of hazmat (hazardous material) like batteries which pose a safety risk.*

The question comes in specifically with luggage; this is because unlike cargo, luggage is subject to some restrictions - mainly due to the existing infrastructure at airports that limits the type, size and weight of items that can be automatically processed.

In some areas, due to work safety issues - heavy luggage is not allowed as it may need to be manually loaded onto the aircraft.

> I was wondering if there is a maximum luggage weight per passenger
>   (assuming the passenger can pay the additional weight)?

There is no limit to the number of pieces of luggage you can check-in as a passenger; you just have to pay for whatever is above your included allowance. So the total weight of all your luggage is not important.

There is a limit to the weight and size of *an individual piece of luggage* but this is subject to whatever the airline decides.

If you were carrying something that (either by weight, or by dimensions) is not compatible with the existing luggage systems - the airline will accept the item as oversized luggage - for which there are other charges and restrictions.

Comment: Weight limits per item might be influenced by work safety lows, like the ones in my country do not allow people to lift items over 25 kg single handedly. (Although the airlines still allow specials up to 32 kg.)

Comment: I've flown with 300kg of motorcycle, before; it was expensive, and of course needed a forklift (and enough paperwork to need a second forklift) but it can be done.  Mainly, advance notice is the thing you need.  If you tell the airline *exactly* what you intend, several weeks in advance, they'll give you a price and find a way to make it happen if you're willing to pay.

Comment: @MadHatter They can also just carry it without you in the plane but we are talking about something else than luggage allowances then.

Comment: @Relaxed I agree, and so does the OP, who explicitly acknowledges the excess charge, thus making it clear that we're *not* talking about regular luggage allowances (on which a weight limit is most definitely present, and well-known).  I think Flimzy sums it up well in his/her comment above: depending on the weight and size of the object(s) you propose to take, you will need varying amounts of advance notice and money.  My point was only that I've done this myself, with an object *considerably* larger than a suitcase.

Comment: "After all, the same 777 you use to fly a long haul flight is the one that is used to transport everything from aircraft engines to animals" That's not strictly speaking true. Large cargo like that would go in the freight version of the aircraft. Some older aircraft (of the 747 era) can be quickly converted between freight and passenger configurations but any individual 777 is either used for passengers or cargo. For example, 777 freighters have [no windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#/media/File:First_Boeing_777F_Lands_after_B-1_Flight.jpg).

Comment: @MadHatter My interpretation was exactly the opposite, the way I see it the question clearly pertains to luggage allowances (i.e. how much you are allowed to take with you when you show up at the airport with a ticket, whether or not there is an excess charge), as opposed to freight services. But I see your point.